In what golden age short story / novella was the concept of "you can defeat a system by turning the handle farther than it was intended to go"?
I remember reading a short story / novella a couple of decades ago.  At the end of the story, one character says to another that "you can defeat a system by turning its handle further than it is intended to go".
Was it in the story "Spectre General" from 1952?  If not, can some kind soul direct me to the story?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  In a magazine or an anthology?  Do you recall any of the other works packaged with this one?

Almost certanly an anthology.  I used to buy used books of stories - both hardback and softbound - short stories.  Through no fault on my part, I lost most of these books (flood).  I'm trying to rebuild the collection of better books, and was looking for this story

It's not in "The Specter General," I just checked.

Thank you for looking at "the Spectre General".  Getting old means conflagrating facts which are not connected.

It was a future Science Fiction story.  Almost certanly a novella or short story.  Probably in a Ben Bova collection, or in a similar anthology.  I never purchased magazines.

The characters were human.  I thought on another planet.  Characters were male (Almost all characters in golden age SF are male, unless they are romantic interests - not so?)  I thought it was military - like space marines, but this last recollection may not be correct.

It would be easiest if you put all that additional information directly in the question.

Murray Leinster or maybe Eric Frank Russell, I'm sure I've read that one.

Thank you to all for your imput and thoughts on the question about the story.  "Study in Still Life" is indeed the story.  It must ahve been in anthology with  "The Spectre General".  As I mentioned earlier, one of the unfortunate  consequences of getting old is to find a conflation of unrelated facts in your mind.

I believe you're recalling "Study in Still Life" (1959) by Eric Frank Russell.  Originally published in Astounding, January 1959, (which you can read at the Internet Archive), it was collected in The Best of Eric Frank Russell (1978).
The protagonist of the story, an ex-pilot named Purcell, is a minor official stationed on a newly opened planet, learning how to deal with bureaucracy.  At the end he finally finds an accommodation that will get him a promotion.
The introductory blurb teases the quote you recall:

When you discover the laws by which a system operates—never buck them. Help them the way they're already going—but help them your way!

But you're undoubtedly recalling the end of the story:

"I neither ask nor expect the true story of your humiliation," growled Hancock. "So you don't have to cover up with a lot of crazy double-talk."
"Some day," offered Purcell, grinning, "it may dawn upon you that it is possible to buck a system, any system. All you need do is turn the handle the way it goes—only more so!"
"Shut up," said Hancock, "and talk when you can talk sense."

